# Send and run code on remote machine using expect

Tags: java, sockets, expect

Hey I am building distributed system for a project. For that, I have bunch of slave machines and one master machine. The master is supposed to send a java code to slaves, run that java code on slaves and then run a different java code on itself.

The slave's code creates a TCP server socket and waits for master. Master sends the job and they reply back.

So my slave should have already created server socket before master starts requesting connection.

Here's my expect code looks so far

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# Get the list of hosts, one per line #####
set f [open "hosts.txt"]
set hosts [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

# Iterate over the hosts
foreach host $hosts {
    spawn scp Slave.class $username@$host:/home/myDir/Slave.class
    expect "assword:"
    send "$password\r"

    spawn ssh $username@$host
    expect "assword:"
    send "$password\r"

    expect "% "
    send "cd myDir\r"

    expect "% "
    send "nohup java Slave &\r"

    # Tidy up
    expect "% "
    send "exit\r"
}

puts "Running Master code"
puts [exec java Master]
```

When I run this code it works slow, it waits after terminal execute previous line. Is there any way to make it faster.